# Working example of Recognizer PendingIntent flow

Tags: android, wear-os, android-pendingintent

I have the following code setup to launch the voice recognizer with a pendingintent to launch another activity:

```
Intent voiceActivityIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, VoiceActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity (MainActivity.this, 0, 
    voiceActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Intent intent = new Intent (RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
    .putExtra (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
    .putExtra (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT, pendingIntent);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

The documentation states that startActivity can't be used with **RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH**, and using startActivityForResult simply returns the result to the current activity (MainActivity) which is not desired.

I've tried:

```
pendingIntent.send ();
```

but this simply take me to VoiceActivity.class without executing the recognizer.

I'm currently testing on the Android Wear Round API 21 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

just add the following to your code:

```
    // this intent wraps voice recognition intent 
    PendingIntent pendingIntVoice = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    pendingIntVoice.send();
```

In other words, with `pendingIntent.send ();` you're not calling the Voice Recognizer Intent, BUT the Intent that should be automatically called when voice recognition ends (infact you set it with `putExtra (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT, pendingIntent)` line)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar, here's what I came up with and it works. This is inside a Service:

```
//IntentHandlerService extends IntentService
//The intent I want sent back to me after voice recognition is complete...
Intent inputTextIntent = new Intent(this, IntentHandlerService.class);
//...gets wrapped in this PendingIntent...
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, inputTextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
//...and added to the intent aimed for the recognizer...
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT, pendingIntent);
//...which is the one you start.
startActivity(intent);
```